# How to set layout (phtml) in my widget?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, widget

I created my first widget but it's very simple and i want to create my widget with layout(using phtml page).

my widget :

Code in`app/code/local/AP/AD/Block/AD.php`:

```
<?php
class AP_AD_Block_AD
extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
  protected function _toHtml()
  {
    $searchCollection = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->setOrder('popularity', 'desc');
    $searchCollection->getSelect()->limit(3,0);
    $html  = '<div id="widget-topsearches-container">' ;
    $html  = '<input type="text" id="validNumber"/>' ;
    $html  = '<input type="submit" id="validNumber"/>' ;
    $html .= '<div class="widget-topsearches-title">Top Searches</div>';
    foreach($searchCollection as $search){
     $html .= '<div class="widget-topsearches-searchtext">' . $search->query_text . "</div>";
   }
   $html .= "</div>";

   return $html ;
 }

};
```

Code in `app/code/local/AP/AD/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <AP_AD>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </AP_AD>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <AD>
        <class>AP_AD_Block</class>
      </AD>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <AD>
        <class>AP_AD_Helper</class>
      </AD>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

in app/code/local/AP/AD/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <AD_topsearches type="AD/adslValidate">
        <name>AD Validations</name>
        <description type="desc">Check Validate AD</description>
    </AD_topsearches>
</widgets>

<referenceContainer name="content.top">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" name="demoBlock" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml">
        <action method="setData">
            <argument name="id_path" xsi:type="string">category/20</argument>
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Demo Category Title</argument>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

in app/code/local/AP/AD/Helper/data.php

```
<?php
class AP_AD_Helper_Data 
extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

in app/code/etc/modules/AP_AD.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AP_AD>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Cms />
            </depends>
        </AP_AD>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: This is a Magento 2 right ?

Comment: no it's magento 1.9

Comment: I don't understand your module, it works for you ? you have merged magento 1 and 2, `widget.xml`

Comment: Hello this is a simple widget for magento 1.9 i just use this link :
http://tablighrank.com/2017/07/26/how-to-create-custom-widget-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code and what you want exactly but, if you need to set your phtml in layout you have to do this:

**app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <namespace_module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
      </namespace_module>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <namespace_module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
      </namespace_module>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <namespace_module>
                <file>namespace_module.xml</file> //the layout
            </namespace_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/layout/namespace_module.xml**

add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <yourRooter_controllerName_actionName>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom.block" template="customtemplate/custom.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </yourRooter_controllerName_actionName>
</layout>
```

You create your `phtml` for exemple in:

**app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/customtemplate/custom.phtml**

```
<h2>Welcome to my new custom phtml</h2>
```

Comment: Hello my code is for create widget on magento.
I just need to add layout with phtml file to widget.
And i don't understand Block and call my phtml to widget.
But thank you for your answer.